# Is it possible to place custom values (properties) in ejb-jar.xml?

Tags: ejb, openejb, custom-properties, ejb-jar.xml

1) We are using OpenEJB (both embedded and standalone) with a few deployed EJBs. We would like to specify some simple static business rules and values (example: icon_size=200). Normally, we would put them in a regular properties file (example: rules.properties). Since we shouldn't access the file system directly while inside the application server, is is possible to place those key-value pairs somewhere inside the ejb-jar.xml?

2) If not, is there a standard mechanism to do this? What is it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use env-entry.  In XML:

```
<env-entry>
  <env-entry-name>icon_size</env-entry-name>
  <env-entry-type>java.lang.Integer</env-entry-type>
  <env-entry-value>200</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

In annotation:

```
@Resource(name="icon_size")
int icon_size;
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally just use a .properties file; well a TernarySearchTree which reads in .properties and .XML files and allows quick retrieval. These files are available at application level.  However you can in EJB 3 inject env-entry elements into your EJB.  This link explains it in good detail [Injection of env entry](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/injection-of-env-entry/README.html)

Comment: Oops, you answered before me :-). +1

Answer (score 0):

There are some OpenEJB extensions here that might be useful.

#### env-entries.properties

Check out the [Custom Injection](http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/custom-injection.html) example which is basically allows the `<env-entry>` to be specified as plain properties in a `META-INF/env-entries.properties` file.  Nice for collapsing all those name & value pairs into a simple properties file.  Internally, we just generate the xml for you using those properties.  The default type is always java.lang.String, which is good for this next part.

#### java.beans.PropertyEditor support

Any `<env-entry>` which is of `<env-entry-type>` `java.lang.String` will automatically have its type converted using the VM `java.beans.PropertyEditor` for the target type.  That's also how Spring does the converting.  There are few built-in converters, such as `@Resource java.util.Date myDate` and `@Resource java.io.File myFile`